# PHP - Connection failed: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I am facing this error. tried all solutions given in other threads...creating a new user@localhost and grant privileges to it.
But nothing works for me...

still getting this **error**..

> Connection failed: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

here is my code..

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "databasename";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
    echo "Connection Successful";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Well it looks like it should work

Comment: The issue is on your MySQL configuration then (assuming you are using the correct username and password). Did you grant privileges to the "username" account on localhost? Did you flush privileges after? Is the account actually created with the proper "IDENTIFIED BY" clause for the "password"?

Comment: It's most likely not an issue with your PHP code, but with your actual MYSQL configuration as mentioned above.

Comment: Do you use same connection parameters with phpmyadmin?

Comment: if you use phpmyadmin look on users and check if your user have correct host for access. http://webvaultwiki.com.au/(S(iungfwenvz2f5c55pioeinil))/GetFile.aspx?File=/images/screenshots/mysql/phpmyadmin04.png

Comment: yes, i created a separate user for my database..and also grant all privileges to it...

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: @BeetleJuice Not yer :-(

Comment: I had another idea and expanded my answer. Take a look

Comment: @BeetleJuice   still the same problem :"(

Answer (score 1):

1 of 2 things is probably happening

1. Your password is incorrect
2. `username` is not authorized to access that database

What do you get when you execute execute following query

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; SHOW GRANTS;
```

You can probably find [your problem here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html).

**Update July 4,2016**

I suspect that the user's password was stored incorrectly. Try resetting the password (you may need to be connected as the root user for this to work):

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost'
    -> IDENTIFIED BY 'cleartext_password';
```

If that doesn't work you could try the older syntax:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('cleartext_password');
```

Replace `cleartext_password` with the password you wish to use. Then try to connect again.

Does it work?

> still the same problem :'(

Ok, let's start with a fresh new user. Execute the 3 commands below as the `root` user.

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'cleartext_password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If all 3 commands executed properly, try next to connect to your database as `newuser`.

Did it work? If not, what error do you see?

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
      GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `databasename`.* TO 'weirdmyth'@'localhost' 
      GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: still the same problem :'(

Comment: I've added to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Some thing wrong with username or password

If you are using  windows by default username is "root" and password is "" (empty),

Comment: no i m not using root....i created a separate user for that database...and also grant all privileges to it ...and also m using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Also, using root and "" empty password didn't work neither